# Alternate screen on FreeBSD's sc and vt

Tags: terminal, freebsd, console, termcap

By default, FreeBSD's virtual terminals (sc and vt) don't restore previous terminal content when exiting from a full screen app. Is there a support for this functionality? I've tried following sequences:

```
\E7\E[r\E[?47h
\E[?47l\E8
```

but they clear the terminal (first one seems to start the alternate screen, and the second one to leave it, however it clears screen).

Comment: Looks like no, as after `pkg install ncurses` and then `infocmp | grep -o '[sr]mcup[^,]*'` with `TERM=screen` the proper escape sequences are shown, and will do the alternate screen thing over a SSH session, but will not in the console with the same `TERM` setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In FreeBSD 10.2, neither syscons nor vt support an alternate display buffer.  It is not implemented in teken.

Answer (score 1):

No - sc and vt are not really xterm-compatible.  Likewise teken.  The first two are essentially `cons25` (25-line "SCO-like" console), and the last you might call xterm-compromise.  The notion behind teken was to lessen distress of people who happen to be on the console and ssh to some other machine where `cons25` is unknown.  It amends some of the function keys, and some of the screen-updating.

In [ncurses](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.html), those have accurate terminal descriptions (with notes):

- [cons25](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-cons25)
- [teken](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/terminfo.src.html#tic-teken)

To get a better sense of the differences of `teken` from `xterm`, you might try running [`vttest`](http://invisible-island.net/vttest/vttest.html), e.g.,

```
vttest 25x80.80
```

(to avoid getting distracted by the lack of support for 80/132-column switching).  For validating the terminal descriptions, [`tack`](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/tack.html) was more useful.

If those terminals had supported alternate screen, there would be a note in the terminal database, and (likely) the `smcup` and `rmcup` capabilities would be filled out to demonstrate it.